# mysql: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now -> when query is run in php function

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Having this code:

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_login=?;";
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
            die(mysqli_error($conn));
        } else {
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $login);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            mysqli_store_result($conn);

            $resultCheck = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);

            //err == login name is already taken
            if ($resultCheck > 0) {
                die("login is taken");
            } else {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO users(user_login, user_email, user_pwd) VALUES (?, ?, ?);";
                $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
                if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
                    die(mysqli_error($conn));
                } else {
                    $hashedPwd = password_hash($pwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sss', $login, $email, $hashedPwd);
                    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                }
                // insert_usertodb($conn, $login, $email, $pwd);
            }
        }
```

works fine (`e.g. the part where is user inserted does not gives any mysqli error), however, if I tried to use a function, where the user is inserted:

```
function insert_usertodb($conn, $user_login, $user_email, $user_pwd)
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users(user_login, user_email, user_pwd) VALUES (?, ?, ?);";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) { // <-- this is where the error happens
        // err_signup('sqlierror', '', '');
        die('sqlierror: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
    } else {
        //hash password
        $hashedPwd = password_hash($user_pwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sss', $user_login, $user_email, $hashedPwd);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        // header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=success");
    }
}
```

And use it instead of the part, where the user is inserted (after `else` branch -> the function is commented at the end), the mysqli generates error:

```
 Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
```

Is there any reason, why the function with identical code (like literally copied the part (where is the insertion) and just change the variables name to be the argument that function) generates the out-of-sync error? and the code without the func doesn't?

Comment: If you are only starting to learn PHP then you should learn PDO instead of mysqli. PDO is much easier and more suitable for beginners. Start here https://phpdelusions.net/pdo & https://websitebeaver.com/php-pdo-prepared-statements-to-prevent-sql-injection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you used a wrong function here `mysqli_store_result($conn);`. You should have used `mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);` instead. This means that your code is not working as you wanted it to and the check for existence is broken. This is why it is a terrible idea to use `mysqli_stmt_num_rows()`.

The reason why it works when it is not in the function is that you call the destructor on the `$stmt` object when you assign it a different value in `$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);`. When a destructor is called it will fetch all results in the background to "clean" the wire.

If it is not too late consider using PDO instead. It is simpler and you won't be making such mistakes so often. The code which you have written with mysqli is too verbose. You don't need most of it. This would be so much easier with PDO.